# C# SpecialFolders enumeration does not include Libraries Folder

Tags: c#, special-folders

The question title is seemingly straight forward and self-explanatory. The issue is that the SpecialFolders enumeration does not include Libraries Folder and I really need to access it and display its folders in a ListBox. Is there any way to do this please?

Comment: Can you give us your code to improve it?

Comment: Does [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65535/Windows-Libraries-C-Quick-Reference) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path to the Libraries folder is `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries`, you can use `SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`, which on Windows is the same as the `%APPDATA%` environment variable:

```
var appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(
        Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

var librariesFolder = Path.Combine(appData, @"Microsoft\Windows\Libraries");
```

Another way to get the full path is to just expand the environment variable:

```
var librariesFolder = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
        @"%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries");
```

Anyways, this is Windows specific and won't work on other platforms, which is pretty much the single good reason to use `Environment.SpecialFolder` in the first place.